# Issue when robot tries to align with target orientation

Tags: navigation, amcl, nav2

I am using AMCL + Nav2 Stack for my custom robot to localize and navigate. When I send a target pose, the robot moves toward it properly. However, when it reaches the target position and tries to align with corresponding orientation, only Z+ rotation is commanded (even if Z- rotation is closer). Additionally, it seems like always is commanded an "approx 90°" rotation as shown in video [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1guaMQGZ3EAFn-44P7Xn_7ITrvFjTemr1/view?usp=sharing). I mean, for example in video, a ~270° rotation should be commanded, but robot stops after "~90°" and then it tries again.

How could I fix it?

Below my yaml file:

```
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 30
    max_particles: 6000
    min_particles: 1500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "differential"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.0
    update_min_d: 0.0
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    first_map_only_: true
    set_initial_pose: true
    initial_pose:
      x: 0.63
      y: 0.35
      yaw: 0.98

amcl_map_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

amcl_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    default_bt_xml_filename: "navigate_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml"
    plugin_lib_names:
    - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
    - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
    - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
    - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
    - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
    - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
    - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
    - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
    - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node

bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    controller_frequency: 10.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.15
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.4
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 1.0
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.4
      min_speed_theta: 0.65
      # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
      # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
      acc_lim_x: 0.4
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 1.0
      decel_lim_x: -0.4
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -1.0
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 0
      vtheta_samples: 40
      sim_time: 1.5
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.3
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.23
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.125
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.125
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0
      
controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
      rolling_window: true
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
      robot_radius: 0.325
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        inflation_radius: 1.0
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          obstacle_min_range: 0.3
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      static_layer:
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
      robot_radius: 0.325
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          obstacle_min_range: 0.3
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    yaml_filename: "map.yaml"

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: False
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_astar: false
      allow_unknown: true

planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

recoveries_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    recovery_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/BackUp"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Wait"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    use_sim_time: False
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.3
    min_rotational_vel: 0.95
    rotational_acc_lim: 1.5

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    loop_rate: 2000
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"   
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200
```

And console output

```
[bt_navigator-7] [INFO] [1701752109.539673688] [bt_navigator]: Begin navigating from current location to (0.46, 0.27)
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752109.565596888] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752109.568304632] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752110.668397880] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752111.668400376] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752112.668377304] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752113.583121592] [DWBLocalPlanner]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752113.583233976] [DWBLocalPlanner]: 1.00: RotateToGoal/Nonrotation command near goal.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752113.583905976] [controller_server]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [WARN] [1701752113.584055736] [controller_server_rclcpp_node]: [follow_path] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752113.595312024] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the local_costmap
[planner_server-5] [INFO] [1701752113.598336984] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752113.600226136] [recoveries_server]: Attempting spin
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752113.600428664] [recoveries_server]: Turning 1.57 for spin recovery.
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752114.600626680] [recoveries_server]: spin running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752115.500700184] [recoveries_server]: spin completed successfully
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752115.525765976] [recoveries_server]: Attempting wait
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752116.527747416] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752117.527858456] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752118.527764824] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752119.527745048] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752120.527754136] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752120.527907832] [recoveries_server]: wait completed successfully
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752120.575548664] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752120.576310872] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752120.590147960] [DWBLocalPlanner]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752120.590230776] [DWBLocalPlanner]: 1.00: RotateToGoal/Nonrotation command near goal.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752120.591090840] [controller_server]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [WARN] [1701752120.591227672] [controller_server_rclcpp_node]: [follow_path] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752120.605322744] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the local_costmap
[planner_server-5] [INFO] [1701752120.607005688] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752120.608532440] [recoveries_server]: Attempting spin
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752120.608871800] [recoveries_server]: Turning 1.57 for spin recovery.
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752121.609116984] [recoveries_server]: spin running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752122.609081112] [recoveries_server]: spin running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752123.609092024] [recoveries_server]: spin running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752124.110299096] [recoveries_server]: spin completed successfully
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752124.136380024] [recoveries_server]: Attempting wait
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752125.136665976] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752126.136667256] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752127.136667256] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752128.136686264] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752129.136684024] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752129.136719896] [recoveries_server]: wait completed successfully
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752129.185378296] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752129.186740792] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752129.200447128] [DWBLocalPlanner]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752129.200525016] [DWBLocalPlanner]: 1.00: RotateToGoal/Nonrotation command near goal.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752129.201253144] [controller_server]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [WARN] [1701752129.201386712] [controller_server_rclcpp_node]: [follow_path] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752129.225973784] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the local_costmap
[planner_server-5] [INFO] [1701752129.227408472] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752129.228770488] [recoveries_server]: Attempting spin
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752129.230064376] [recoveries_server]: Turning 1.57 for spin recovery.
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752130.230411864] [recoveries_server]: spin running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752131.230426744] [recoveries_server]: spin running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752132.230579256] [recoveries_server]: spin running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752132.730509304] [recoveries_server]: spin completed successfully
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752132.755859928] [recoveries_server]: Attempting wait
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752133.756108920] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752134.756115032] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752135.756188600] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752136.756094744] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752137.756787096] [recoveries_server]: wait completed successfully
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752137.757328760] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752137.805736056] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752137.826078008] [DWBLocalPlanner]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752137.826165496] [DWBLocalPlanner]: 1.00: RotateToGoal/Nonrotation command near goal.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752137.827141176] [controller_server]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [WARN] [1701752137.827508760] [controller_server_rclcpp_node]: [follow_path] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752137.827893112] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752137.848144600] [DWBLocalPlanner]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752137.848247960] [DWBLocalPlanner]: 1.00: RotateToGoal/Nonrotation command near goal.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752137.849050488] [controller_server]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [WARN] [1701752137.849325656] [controller_server_rclcpp_node]: [follow_path] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752137.865309912] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the local_costmap
[planner_server-5] [INFO] [1701752137.866975160] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752137.868553976] [recoveries_server]: Attempting spin
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752137.868726456] [recoveries_server]: Turning 1.57 for spin recovery.
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752138.868961944] [recoveries_server]: spin running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752139.869036088] [recoveries_server]: spin running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752140.868913144] [recoveries_server]: spin running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752141.369127960] [recoveries_server]: spin completed successfully
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752141.395723512] [recoveries_server]: Attempting wait
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752142.396120184] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752143.396150616] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752144.396048696] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752145.396144248] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752146.396052408] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752146.396197912] [recoveries_server]: wait completed successfully
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752146.445437240] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752146.469604376] [DWBLocalPlanner]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752146.469689272] [DWBLocalPlanner]: 1.00: RotateToGoal/Nonrotation command near goal.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752146.470578424] [controller_server]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [WARN] [1701752146.470711096] [controller_server_rclcpp_node]: [follow_path] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752146.470947032] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752146.486131928] [DWBLocalPlanner]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752146.486204504] [DWBLocalPlanner]: 1.00: RotateToGoal/Nonrotation command near goal.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752146.486984216] [controller_server]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [WARN] [1701752146.487276312] [controller_server_rclcpp_node]: [follow_path] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752146.505322520] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the local_costmap
[planner_server-5] [INFO] [1701752146.507229496] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752146.508925240] [recoveries_server]: Attempting spin
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752146.509953944] [recoveries_server]: Turning 1.57 for spin recovery.
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752147.510783736] [recoveries_server]: spin running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752148.510777816] [recoveries_server]: spin running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752149.510782552] [recoveries_server]: spin running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752150.010876408] [recoveries_server]: spin completed successfully
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752150.038008024] [recoveries_server]: Attempting wait
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752151.038447416] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752152.038427896] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752153.038414168] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752154.038429496] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752155.038365368] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752155.038396632] [recoveries_server]: wait completed successfully
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752155.087987256] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752155.090652728] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752155.110315224] [DWBLocalPlanner]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752155.111839736] [DWBLocalPlanner]: 1.00: RotateToGoal/Nonrotation command near goal.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752155.113534296] [controller_server]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [WARN] [1701752155.114456504] [controller_server_rclcpp_node]: [follow_path] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752155.128178424] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the local_costmap
[planner_server-5] [INFO] [1701752155.131217272] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752155.132949304] [recoveries_server]: Attempting spin
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752155.133329368] [recoveries_server]: Turning 1.57 for spin recovery.
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752156.133568120] [recoveries_server]: spin running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752157.133614904] [recoveries_server]: spin running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752158.133583672] [recoveries_server]: spin running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752158.733660536] [recoveries_server]: spin completed successfully
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752158.773061656] [recoveries_server]: Attempting wait
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752159.775266744] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752160.775275224] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752161.775263896] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752162.775281720] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752163.775272664] [recoveries_server]: wait running...
[recoveries_server-6] [INFO] [1701752163.775401784] [recoveries_server]: wait completed successfully
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752163.820211448] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752163.835245944] [DWBLocalPlanner]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752163.835338712] [DWBLocalPlanner]: 1.00: RotateToGoal/Nonrotation command near goal.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752163.836075416] [controller_server]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [WARN] [1701752163.836208408] [controller_server_rclcpp_node]: [follow_path] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[controller_server-4] [INFO] [1701752163.836368312] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752163.849465720] [DWBLocalPlanner]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752163.849547384] [DWBLocalPlanner]: 1.00: RotateToGoal/Nonrotation command near goal.
[controller_server-4] [ERROR] [1701752163.850149432] [controller_server]: No valid trajectories out of 820! 
[controller_server-4] [WARN] [1701752163.850271032] [controller_server_rclcpp_node]: [follow_path] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[bt_navigator-7] [ERROR] [1701752163.879514808] [bt_navigator]: Navigation failed
[bt_navigator-7] [WARN] [1701752163.881795672] [bt_navigator]: [navigate_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
```

Thank you

Comment: These look like recovery behaviors enacting, not attempts to orient to the goal.

Comment: You're right, according with console output it looks like recovery behavior. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Off of the top of my head, I'm not sure what could be causing that in DWB tuning. I'd start with Nav2's default algorithms and work back from there!